# AddThis Share button

Tags: blogger, blog, widgets

I wanted to add 'share-button' to my blog hosted by blogger but when I click the 'Install Widget', it's not working, no content/html in the box. [image] 
How to tweak this?

Comment: I already changed it and added image, I hope its clearer now. Thanks :)

Comment: ANSWER:   You don't do this using the "Intall Widget" feature - that's about adding the widget to the Blogger library, not to your blog.   Instead, go to the Blogger dashboard, choose Layout, and then Add Gadget.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ You can add that as an answer now if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do this using the "Intall Widget" feature - that's about adding the widget to the Blogger library, not to your blog.

Instead, go to the Blogger dashboard, choose Layout for your blog, and then Add a Gadget.